From single message two different entity is extracting
I want to extract address and high school from the message. And when I write Boston High School. RegexEntityExtractor extract Boston has location and Diet classifier classify it as high which is correct. I have lookup table for citites and countries which is location. Here RegexEntityExtractor is failing. this is my config file
pipeline: 
# # No configuration for the NLU pipeline was provided. The following default pipeline was used to train your model.
# # If you'd like to customize it, uncomment and adjust the pipeline.
# # See https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/tuning-your-model for more information.
  - name: WhitespaceTokenizer
  - name: RegexFeaturizer
  - name: LexicalSyntacticFeaturizer
  - name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
  - name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
    analyzer: char_wb
    min_ngram: 1
    max_ngram: 4
  - name: RegexEntityExtractor
    # text will be processed with case insensitive as default
    case_sensitive: False
    # use lookup tables to extract entities
    use_lookup_tables: True
    # use regexes to extract entities
    use_regexes: False
    # use match word boundaries for lookup table
    use_word_boundaries: True
  - name: DIETClassifier
    epochs: 100
    constrain_similarities: true

  - name: EntitySynonymMapper
  - name: ResponseSelector
    epochs: 100
    constrain_similarities: true
  - name: FallbackClassifier
    threshold: 0.3
    ambiguity_threshold: 0.1

This is NLU.yml file
- intent: provide_details
  examples: |
    - [Tom Larry](name)
    - [John Doe](name) attended [Boston High school](highschool).
    - [Jacksonville, FL](location)
    - [Hartford Public High School](highschool)
    - [Hopkins Academy](highschool)
    - [Newburgh Free Academy](highschool)
    - He or She attended [English High School of Boston](highschool).
    - [Norwich Free Academy](highschool)
    - [New York high school](highschool)
    - [Diana](name) studied in [Georgia city school](highschool)
    - [Denver High](highschool)
    - [Wilam](name) was born in [Laguna Hills, California](location)
    - [Rahul](name) graduated from [American Hertiage Academy](highschool).
    - [Lucas Scott](name)
    - He is from [Rosharon, TX](location)
    - [Willam Cooper](name)
    - She is [Angela](name)
    - He was from [Georgia](location)
    - [John](name) was from [Georgia High School](highschool)

I tried custom actions
